# Marking chrome extension as "Works with Google Drive"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, chrome-web-store

I developed a chrome extension [Hyperbook saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hyperbook-saver/ipkkcbhjiafgdhjaincandbahdknhpel) that works with Google Drive to save images and texts. How do I enable "Works with Google drive" feature for it. 
I couldn't find any flag in developer Dashboard or manifest.json file. Please help.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by 'enable "Works with Google drive" feature for it'?

Comment: The OP probably refers to the message that appears in some apps like [HTML Editey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-editey/jgmngefpkkgnhkgffnldnpinipphceob) saying that the app "Works with Google Drive". Maybe this has to be done not from the developers dashboard but from [Google Drive API console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive)

Comment: More than adding it to logo I want "Works with Google drive" check working in Search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Chrome extension manifest, you just need to make sure you have:

```
"container": "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
"api_console_project_id": "your developer console project number here",
```

See this manifest as an example: https://github.com/googledrive/zipextractor/blob/master/cws/zipextractor/manifest.json